# Chunk and excel Laravel

Tags: excel, laravel, eloquent

guys.
I need help with this code. I need to download an excel with arround 550000 records. So i was wondering how can i use eloquent with chunk, skip and limit and get to make the excel or do something better than this. I started to making some code to save excel in a folder and then download in a zip, but i cant make works chunk and get.

I had problems with time execution and memory limit, but thats no more a problem.

This is my code.

```
$x=1;
            for ($i=0; $i<=550000; $i=$i+15000) { 
                $personas="";
                $personas = DB::table("cat_personas as c")->select("c.*","s.seccion","ca.casilla")    
                ->leftJoin("cat_casillas as ca","c.cat_casilla_id","=","ca.id") 
                ->join("cat_seccion as s","c.cat_seccion_id","=","s.id")    
                ->where($filtros) 
                ->whereRaw("c.id NOT IN ( SELECT cruzado FROM registro_persona )")  
                ->whereRaw($whereCadena)  
                ->orderby('c.consecutivo')   
                ->orderby('c.apellido_paterno')   
                ->orderby('c.apellido_materno')   
                ->orderby('c.nombre')   
                ->orderby('s.seccion')  
                ->orderby('ca.casilla') 
                ->skip($i)->limit(15000);

                //$personas=$personas->get();
                dd($personas->count());
                if($personas->count()>0){
                    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
                    $r=1;
                    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()       
                    ->setCellValue('A'.$r, '#')
                    ->setCellValue('B'.$r, 'NOMBRE')
                    ->setCellValue('C'.$r, 'APELLIDO PATERNO')
                    ->setCellValue('D'.$r, 'APELLIDO MATERNO')
                    ->setCellValue('E'.$r, 'SECCION')
                    ->setCellValue('F'.$r, 'CASILLA')
                    ->setCellValue('G'.$r, 'CONSECUTIVO');
                    $r++;
                     $personas->chunk(5000, function($personas) use (&$spreadsheet,&$r,&$sheet) {              
                            $c=1;
                            //dd($personas->count());
                            foreach ($personas as $key) {
                            $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()       
                            ->setCellValue('A'.$r, $c)
                            ->setCellValue('B'.$r, $key->nombre)
                            ->setCellValue('C'.$r, $key->apellido_paterno)
                            ->set`enter code here`CellValue('D'.$r, $key->apellido_materno)
                            ->setCellValue('E'.$r, $key->seccion)
                            ->setCellValue('F'.$r, $key->casilla)
                            ->setCellValue('G'.$r, $key->consecutivo);
                            $r++;
                            $c++;
                            }
                    });
                    $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
                    //header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
                    //header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="personas.xlsx"');
                    $writer->save($path."/personas$x.xlsx");
                    $x++;
                }
            }
```

Comment: laravel has built-int chunk support https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#chunking-results

Comment: What package are you using to create the spreadsheet? What are the errors you are facing? PS, XLSX files are actually already zipped. If you rename a .xlsx file to .zip, you can open it and see the files within.

Comment: Im using use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet; V1.9. And the problem is that chunk doesnt work with get in eloquent.

Comment: define your $spreadsheet and $writer save out of for loop

Comment: @SergioFimbres , You are correct, get doesn't work with chunk. Are you having issues because without the get, the if $personas->count will return 0?

Comment: @WillWalsh I see. The problem is that without get it returns all records (500k). And chunk take it. So limit and skip doest work without Get, so chunk get all records and it make Internal Server Error.

Comment: @SergioFimbres - Have you tried using lazy collections? After you remove `skip($i)->limit(15000)`, use `$personas->lazy()->each(function($persona) { // code to add row to spreadsheet here });`

Comment: @WillWalsh no, but i would llike to use it. why use that? is better for lot of records?

Comment: @SergioFimbres - Lazy loading is like chunking, but, from my understanding, you only load one record at a time. I will write a full answer with how I would rewrite what you have to use lazy. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use chunk() this way.

```
$personas = DB::table("cat_personas as c")->select("c.*","s.seccion","ca.casilla")    
  ->leftJoin("cat_casillas as ca","c.cat_casilla_id","=","ca.id") 
  ->join("cat_seccion as s","c.cat_seccion_id","=","s.id")    
  ->where($filtros) 
  ->whereRaw("c.id NOT IN ( SELECT cruzado FROM registro_persona )")  
  ->whereRaw($whereCadena)  
  ->orderby('c.consecutivo')   
  ->orderby('c.apellido_paterno')   
  ->orderby('c.apellido_materno')   
  ->orderby('c.nombre')   
  ->orderby('s.seccion')  
  ->orderby('ca.casilla');
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$r = 1;
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()       
  ->setCellValue('A'.$r, '#')
  ->setCellValue('B'.$r, 'NOMBRE')
  ->setCellValue('C'.$r, 'APELLIDO PATERNO')
  ->setCellValue('D'.$r, 'APELLIDO MATERNO')
  ->setCellValue('E'.$r, 'SECCION')
  ->setCellValue('F'.$r, 'CASILLA')
  ->setCellValue('G'.$r, 'CONSECUTIVO');
$r++;
$c = 1;
$personas->chunk(500, function($personae) use ($spreadsheet, $r, $c) {
  foreach ($personae as $persona) {
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()       
      ->setCellValue('A'.$r, $c)
      ->setCellValue('B'.$r, $persona->nombre)
      ->setCellValue('C'.$r, $persona->apellido_paterno)
      ->setCellValue('D'.$r, $persona->apellido_materno)
      ->setCellValue('E'.$r, $persona->seccion)
      ->setCellValue('F'.$r, $persona->casilla)
      ->setCellValue('G'.$r, $persona->consecutivo);
    $r++;
    $c++;
  }
});
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save($path . "/personas.xlsx");
```

There might be an issue with the total size of the spreadsheet, but if so, this should be a good start towards finding that solution.

PS - This is untested.

Comment: Thx so much. But i had this error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::lazy() do u know why?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Im using Laravel 7

Comment: Just my luck. lazy() was introduced in Laravel 8. Let me rethink the chunk method.

Comment: @SergioFimbres - I've just updated back to using chunk(). Hopefully this works for you.

Comment: Thx so much Will. Im testing now. but it showed a error. Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. And it happend cause its alot of information

Comment: @SergioFimbres - Can you see the system logs? This could be a simple timeout, which is pretty likely, an error with Laravel/Eloquent or, in my opinion more likely, with the Spreadsheet package.

Comment: No, i dont have any error in logs. Not public folder, and not laravel. But it take a lot of time to do the job with 500,000 records. So im stuck. Memory limit =-1 and max_execution_time= 18000.

Comment: Can you access the DB manually? Perhaps you need to run this query directly on the DB, likely getting the data in sections.

Comment: if i run this query in db manually, its takes 3 seconds to get all data with indexes. And to get data in sections i was trying to do that with skip and limits and then save excels in parts of 15,000 records. But i dont know what to do cause it shows the same error 500. I tried everything i know.

Comment: If it is running that quickly manually, I would say this is an issue with the Spreadsheet package rather than Laravel/Eloquent or PHP. What happens if you remove the code to create the spreadsheet? Does it still give the 500 error?

Comment: Well, it ts spreadsheet 1.9. With chunk 500 and without any library, just using php,laravel/eloquent and printing each loop, it take 1000 loops cause there are 500,000 (records)/500(records to proccess with chunk)=1000 loops. Lot of time. I know that i can increse chunk to 1000 o 2000. But what can i do with library excel to process this data.